sns.jointplotで点のサイズを変更する方法がわかりません。
以下のコードを実行したとき、エラーは出ないのですがcsvファイルに記載されているSize列の数値通りに出力されません。エラーも出ないのでなぜこうなるのかよくわかりません。
csvファイルの内容は以下のようになります。
U1,U2,Li,Size
0.56, 0.89, D, 10
0.875, 0.52, M, 10
0.234, 0.827, AE, 10
0.62, 0.19, D, 10
0.25, 0.52, M, 10
0.14, 0.327, AE, 10
0.89, 0.32, PD, 40
0.76, 0.65, O, 40

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
#ラベルごとの色を指定するためのカスタムパレットを定義する
label_palette = {'D': 'orangered', 'M': 'forestgreen', 'AE': 'deepskyblue', 'PD': 'darkblue', 'O': 'yellow'}
#jointplotの作成
plot = sns.jointplot(x='U1', y='U2', sizes = "Size", data=df, hue='Li', palette=label_palette, height=8, space=0.3)
#プロットの軸にアクセスし、凡例の位置を設定する
plt.legend()
plt.show()


もしかしたら seaborn.jointplot だけでは出来ずに seaborn.scatterplot と組み合わせる必要があるかもしれませんね。Seaborn: How to change size of spots in a JointPlot according to feature?
